# Display a docx file on the screen

Tags: django

I created a ms-word document using MailMerge in django. It´s worked ok.
Right now, i´d like to show this file on screen. I write the code bellow, but it didn´t work.

views.py

```
with open(file_path) as doc:
   response = HttpResponse(doc.read(), content_type='application/ms-word')
   response = HttpResponse(template_output)
   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=var_nomdocumento_output'
```

error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\GROWTHTECH\\Projetos\\blockchain\\media_root/procuracao'
```

Comment: the `Content-Disposition` should be `inline`. that way: `response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename`

Comment: thank you, but it didn´t work. In this case I include the path and file names, and I have a new error:     with open("C:/GROWTHTECH/Projetos/blockchain/media_root/procuracao/49-teste.docx") as doc:
        response = HttpResponse(doc.read(), content_type='application/ms-word')
        response = HttpResponse("49-teste.docx")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename="49-teste.docx"'

Comment: the new error: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 71: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: what is `template_output`, can you add its value?

Comment: I include a simple code above, but it didn´t work.

Comment: did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to provide the **binary open mode**. It can be `r` open for reading (default) `w` open for writing, truncating the file first, `b` for binary mode.

so In our case: It will be `rb`

```
file_path = 'path/path/file.docx'
with open(file_path,'rb') as doc:
   response = HttpResponse(doc.read(), content_type='application/ms-word')
   # response = HttpResponse(template_output)
   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=name.docx'
   return response
```

No browsers currently render Word Documents as far as I know. So your file will be automatically downloaded whatever the parameter is: `'attachment;filename="file_name"'` or `'inline;filename="file_name"'`